# image input type not being detected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I am trying to submit a form using an **image input type**. The ajax request performs fine, and I get a response back from my php script. My problem is that I want the image button to change it's image when it is submitted (and it wasn't doing that). The firebug console said that form.pic is undefined, and the image does not get updated. Any Ideas why?

**javascript/jquery**

```
function new_user(form){

    var url = "attendance.php";

    var dataString = "status="+form.astatus.value;
    dataString = dataString+"&id="+form.mark_attend.value;
    $.ajax({  
type: "POST",  
url: url, 
data: dataString,  
success: function(data) {
form.pic.src = data; //Error here
},
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ console.error("error: " + textStatus, errorThrown);}
});

return false;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form method="POST" onSubmit="return new_user(this);" >
<input type="hidden" value="attended" name="astatus" />
<input type="hidden" value="idKey" name="mark_attend" />
<input type="image" src="greencheck.png" name="pic" />
</form>
```

Comment: input type image is not part of the form elements collection, hence why it does not work.

Comment: Since you are using jQuery `$(form).find('input[name="pic"]').prop("src",data);`

Comment: very nice, that did the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(form).find('input[name="pic"]').attr('src', data);
```

This, I think, is the cleanest way to do this considering that you are using jQuery.

Comment: Very nice! that get's me halfway through my problem. The image is changing when clicked, but I probably should have provided more information. Is it possible to reference only the "pic" within the form I'm submitting? I have multiple identical forms, that get echoed out by a php script. so for example `form.pic` ?

Comment: @dmkumar I've updated my answer. If you are creating the forms dynamically and you can't assign an id for them manually let me know.

Comment: There is no reason for an id! Yikes `$(form).find...`

Comment: Very nice, Thank you both!

Comment: @epascarello I never said it was necessary, but if he can assign an id to his forms, it is better than passing said form _as a parameter_.

Comment: That is your opinion and to me it is NOT better than passing the parameter. You could have multiple forms on the page and all you need is a reference to what submitted it. No need to have multiple functions or change code to behave differently.

Comment: @epascarello Well, in this case you are right because he's dynamically creating multiple forms that perform the same exact action.